# ¿Cómo saber si un objeto está contenido en un array?

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo el siguiente `Array` desde un `select` que contiene los IDs de una tabla:

```
var arreglo = ["1", "2", "4", "5"]
```

Quiero saber si `"3"` está contenido en `arreglo`. En Python es posible hacer esto:

```
>>> arreglo = ['1', '2', '4', '5']
>>> '3' in arreglo
False
```

Pero intentando esto desde la consola en JavaScript me di con la sorpresa de que no funciona de la misma manera:

```
> var arreglo = ["1", "2", "4", "5"]
> "3" in arreglo
true
```

Investigando un poco en la [documentación de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) encontré el problema (énfasis de mi parte):

> El operador `in` retorna true si la **propiedad** especificada se encuentra en el objeto especificado.

Efectivamente, `arreglo` cuenta con la propiedad (o índice) `"3"`, es por eso que me retorna `true`:

```
> Object.keys(arreglo)
["0", "1", "2", "3"]
```

Mi consulta, ¿como puedo hacer entonces para validar que un objeto está contenido dentro de un arreglo?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Puedes usar la función `indexOf` de la clase `Array`, que devuelve la posición donde se encuentra el objeto buscado.

```
arreglo.indexOf("3") >= 0
```

Devuelve `-1` si no existe, y en caso contrario la posición que será mayor o igual que `0`.

Comment: Me parece que es la mas directa y sencilla, gracias por tu aporte!

Answer (score 4):

Puedes usar un simple script como:

```
<script>    
var arreglo = ["1", "2", "4", "5"]            
for(var i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
    alert("se encuentra " + arreglo[i]);
    if (arreglo[i] == "4") {
        alert("se encuentra objeto!.");
        break;
    }
}
</script>
```

Aunque basándome en tu pregunta `¿Cómo saber si un objeto está contenido en un array?`, para mi un objeto sería por ejemplo:

```
arreglo = [
    {
      indice: 'a',
      valor: '1'
     },
    {
      indice: 'b',
      valor: '2'
     },
    {
      indice: 'b',
      valor: '4'
     },
    {
      indice: 'd',
      valor: '5'
     },
];
```

Ahora, para determinar si existe el objeto `"b"` sería mediante:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
    if (arreglo[i].valor== 'b') {
          alert("se encuentra objeto!.");
        break;
    }
}
```

Pero como comentas, para mi sería también suficiente usar únicamente el método [**indexOf()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53xtt423(v=vs.94).aspx): `arreglo.indexOf('3') > -1`

Comment: Tu solución es válida, un poco mas extensa, pero válida finalmente. Creo que mejor sería usar `indexOf()`  como mencionan, es lo que mas se acerca a lo que quiero lograr. Gracias!

Answer (score 4):

Investigando un poco en MDN, hay un método `Array.prototype.includes()` propuesto para EcmaScript 2016 (ES7) y regresa un valor booleano si el arreglo contiene el elemento indicado:

```
[1, 2, 3].includes(3); // true
["a", "b", "c"].includes("d"); // false
```

Este método acepta un segundo parámetro opcional, que indica a partir de qué índice se realizará la búsqueda (0 por default).

```
["foo", "bar", "baz"].includes("baz", 1); // true
```

Aún no es oficial que el método esté presente en la próxima versión de JavaScript, pero de estarlo esta respuesta será más relevante y me parece una buena adición a los Arrays porque permite expresar nuestra intención claramente, lo que produce un código más legible. Actualmente es posible probarlo en las últimas versiones de los navegadores más habituales excepto IE y Edge (sorpresivamente).

En la [documentación oficial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) encontramos el siguiente *polyfill*:

```
if (!Array.prototype.includes) {
  Array.prototype.includes = function(searchElement /*, fromIndex*/ ) {
    'use strict';
    var O = Object(this);
    var len = parseInt(O.length) || 0;
    if (len === 0) {
      return false;
    }
    var n = parseInt(arguments[1]) || 0;
    var k;
    if (n >= 0) {
      k = n;
    } else {
      k = len + n;
      if (k < 0) {k = 0;}
    }
    var currentElement;
    while (k < len) {
      currentElement = O[k];
      if (searchElement === currentElement ||
         (searchElement !== searchElement && currentElement !== currentElement))     { // NaN !== NaN
        return true;
      }
      k++;
    }
    return false;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Si no te interesa ser compatible con los navegadores IE6, 7 u 8, puedes usar simplemente usar [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/indexOf) como se indica en la primera respuesta.

```
function inArray(arreglo, elemento) {
  return arreglo.indexOf(elemento) !== -1;
}
```

Ahora si necesitas ser compatible con navegadores "historicos", podrias implementar `indexOf` tu mismo. El siguiente código puede ser agregado con seguridad a tu codigo ya que si `indexOf` esta definido no tiene ningún efecto:

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function (obj, fromIndex) {
    if (fromIndex == null) {
        fromIndex = 0;
    } else if (fromIndex < 0) {
        fromIndex = Math.max(0, this.length + fromIndex);
    }
    for (var i = fromIndex, j = this.length; i < j; i++) {
        if (this[i] === obj)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
  };
}
```

Nota: esta implemetacion de `indexOf` fue publicada originalmente por [Daniel James](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143847/best-way-to-find-if-an-item-is-in-a-javascript-array#144172).

Comment: Buena respuesta! Con información adicional, gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Tomando en cuenta que tenemos:

```
var arreglo = ["1", "2", "4", "5"];
```

### Solución 1 - Nativa

Tenemos la siguiente función y la documentación [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/indexOf):

> array.indexOf(searchElement[, fromIndex])

Uso práctico:

```
arreglo.indexOf('1'); // Devuelve 0
arreglo.indexOf('3'); // Devuelve -1
```

### Solución 2 - Uso de librerías

Podemos utilizar herramientas de 3ros para lograr obtener dicho resultado, como lo son:

---

#### - Utilizando [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)

Documentación de [jQuery.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/):

> jQuery.inArray( value, array [, fromIndex ] )

Uso práctico:

```
$.inArray('3', arreglo); // Devuelve -1
```

---

#### - Utilizando [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)

Documentación de [_.indexOf()](http://underscorejs.org/#indexOf):

> _.indexOf(array, value, [isSorted])

Uso práctico:

```
_.indexOf(arreglo, '3'); // Devuelve -1
```